# Text has unnecessary spacing underneath it

Tags: css

This is probably an easy one, and I've tried what I've seen from other search results, but no dice.

Here is some text I've highlighted (the text 'TODAY').  You can see some space at the bottom of the text.  I'd like this text to be well-cantered with the chevrons, so I want it centered.

## What I have tried

- remove paddings/margins
- line-height: 1
- text-decoration: none
- text-align: center
- vertical-align: middle

I've tried all of the above css properties on my `<p>` tag, but still nothing.

How do I get this text vertically centered to line up with the chevrons?

[image]

Comment: Can you share HTML please ?

Comment: In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: most likely a line-height issue :)

Comment: If it's (jump-to-today) always the same height, set the line height to be the same # of pixels (24px in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work.

```
.jump-to-today {
  display: flex;  /* or display: inline-flex */
  align-items: center
}
```